# Mac Mail.app & Smart Mailbox conditions

Tags: mac, email, smart, mailbox

I'm having some trouble with my Smart Mailbox setup.

I've got a Smart Mailbox named "**Unread**".

And Contains **messages** that match **any** of the following conditions:
Message is Unread
Message is not in Mailbox    News (AT) lovejungle.com
Message is not in Mailbox    Info (AT) lovejungle.com

For some reasons, it is still displaying messages in either News@ or Info@. 
I've removed either Not in News@ or Info@ and it still shows messages from each inbox.

Any ideas on what's set up wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tou need to use match all condition

match any means that it will be in the Smart mailbox if any one of the conditions hold. Thus it will fins all your unread and more.

To get a smart mailbox that matches less mails than one rule you need the match and. In your case the mailbox would show only unread and only those not in the named mailboxes.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately i've tried matching all. 

It still shows up messages that are in the News@ mailbox, but as far as I can tell doesn't show messages that are in the Info@ mailbox.

Is there anything else that could be messing with it?

Comment: Can you crete a smart mail box with just the condition you have  for new@ mailbox and does it show what you expect

Comment: @Michael Cannot reproduce. I have three mailboxes with unread messages, the same 3 conditions, and only the unread messages of the mailbox not mentioned in any condition are displayed in the Smart Mailbox. Do you use subfolders? Remember that the Index of each account is different e.g. from Sent, so you need to exclude all of these "folders".

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out by using a different method of filtering.